# Fixtures.loadModels not working in PlayFramework

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm using PlayFramework 1.2.5 and am working on a FunctionalTest shown below

```
public class CaseFoldersControllerTests extends FunctionalTest {

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    Fixtures.deleteDatabase();
    Fixtures.loadModels("data.yml");
  }

  @After
  public void teardown() {
  }

 ...

  @Test
  public void createAction() {
    ....
    Request request = newRequest();
    request.path = "/case/create";
    request.body = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes());
    Response response = makeRequest(request);

    //Verify response is OK
    assertStatus(200, response);
  }
}
```

The data in data.yml is NOT available during the execution of my test (createAction). However, the data *is* in the database after my test completes.

If I move the data loading statements from the @Before method to the @After method...then the test succeeds (since the data is now cleaned up & reset from the prior test).

I'm assuming this is JPA session related, but adding the following after Fixtures.loadModels() didn't help:

```
JPA.em().flush();
```

Also, what's interesting is that the @Before method was copied from my Unit test where it works fine. It's only with the FunctionalTest that I'm having problems.

TIA,
M2

Answer (score 0):

First of all we need to be sure your setUp is really being called, so I would suggest using a Logger inside your method to know that. If it is really being called then I suggest you test your yml without using that Request, maybe by making a findAll() of the models you are trying to insert with your yml. This way we can be sure that what is messing up the code is not your request.

** this has happened to me before..... my @Before was not running because I imported play.MVC.Before, you must import org.junit.Before